# Merge / Diff on the Node-RED flow is very slow

Tags: node-red

We are working on various ChatBot project using Node-Red to design conversation.
But "team work" on v0.19 is really painfull when making diff on the flow.

In a nutshell it takes about 2 minutes to make the diff !

- The file has 32000 lines
- For about 2595 nodes (with 679 nodes function)
- Everything is split in various tabs or subflow (30-40)
- There is almost 60-80 nodes / tabs it's readable for Node-RED it's not an "over-usage"

Any ideas to speed up the GIT Diff ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only realistic answer you are going to get here is use a smaller flow.

It will probably be worth bringing this up on the discourse forum or slack where Nick might be able to look at the code and see if it can be improved. But looking at the [code](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/master/red/runtime/storage/localfilesystem/projects/git/index.js#L570) it looks like it's just calling `git diff` under the covers.

Comment: At first I thought it was too much nodes. But in fact it's only 60 nodes per tab that i really readable. Git Diff on a file is really fast I assume the problem comes from the UI trying to display the diff

Comment: I continue here with Nick https://discourse.nodered.org/t/merge-diff-on-the-node-red-flow-is-very-slow/5095/3